# How to transfer video from the server to the android application?

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, mobile-development

I need to transfer video files from the server to the android application, but in such a way that they are loaded while watching and I can keep them in the cache. I tried to do something with streaming from the server of these videos, but I did not figure out how to keep them in the cache and what headers Response Entity should have in this case, so that the video streaming can be displayed correctly in the application. With such a controller, the player cannot play video.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "video/test/")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getVideoByLink() throws IOException {
        File initialFile = new File("videoFile.mp4");
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"));
        headers.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        headers.set("Expires", "0");
        headers.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        headers.set("Connection", "keep-alive");
        headers.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        headers.set("Charset","UTF-8");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(targetStream), headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Comment: What has the subject of your post to do with the code you posted? And what should that code do?

Comment: Where id that controller?

Comment: Without the intend to offend you, but I think what you want to achieve is way out of your current skills. There is no esay click-and-run solution for that. Even long term developers (years of experience in high end development) will have their issues implementing what you are aiming for.